# Attempt to read property "name" on array (Select with Livewire)

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a dependent select with Livewire.
My problem is that when I load the second select, it loads it without problems, but when I select an option from the second select, it throws me this error.

`Attempt to read property "nombre" on array`

select template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="form-label">Tipo de Inscripcion</label>
            <select wire:model="selectedTipoInscripcion" class="form-select">
                <option selected>Seleccionar ...</option>
                @foreach($tipoInscripcion as $tipo)
                <option value="{{ $tipo -> id }}">{{ $tipo -> nombre}}</option>
                @endforeach()
            </select>
        </div>

        @if(!is_null($tipoPrograma))
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="form-label">Tipo de Programa</label>

            <select wire:model="selectedTipoPrograma" class="form-select">
                <option selected>Seleccionar ...</option>
                @foreach($tipoPrograma as $tipo)
                <option value="{{ $tipo -> id}}">{{ $tipo -> nombre}}</option>
                @endforeach()
            </select>
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is in

```
<option value="{{ $tipo -> id}}">{{ $tipo -> nombre}}</option>
```

My Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Curso;
use App\Models\Programa;
use Livewire\Component;

class SelectAnidado extends Component
{
    public $selectedTipoInscripcion = null, $selectedTipoPrograma = null, $SelectedProgrCur = null;
    public $tipoPrograma = null, $progrCur = null, $sw = null;

    public function render()
    {

        $programa = (object) ['id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'Programa'];

        $curso = (object) ['id' => 2, 'nombre' => 'Curso'];

        $ti = collect([$programa, $curso]);

        return view('livewire.select-anidado', [
            'tipoInscripcion' => $ti
        ]);
    }

    public function updatedselectedTipoInscripcion($id)
    {

        if ($id == 1) {
            $doctorado = (object) ['id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'doctorado'];
            $maestria = (object) ['id' => 2, 'nombre' => 'maestria'];
            $especialidad = (object) ['id' => 3, 'nombre' => 'especialidad'];
            $diplomado = (object) ['id' => 4, 'nombre' => 'diplomado'];
            $this->tipoPrograma = collect([$doctorado, $maestria, $especialidad, $diplomado]);
        }
    }
}
```

It tells me that I am trying to access an array as if it were an object.

But then the error should also appear when the  is loaded.
Why does it only appear when I make the selection?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help related to your question, but a quick tip, follow standards ([PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)), don't write `$object -> property` but `$object->property`, don't declare properties on a single line like `public $property1 = null, $property2 = null;`, do it in single lines, and I would also like to say, add the type, `public ?string $property1 = null;`, `public array $property2 = [];`, etc... And, ALWAYS code in english, if you need to share code that is in spanish, only you will understand it

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is here :

```
$this->tipoPrograma = collect([$doctorado, $maestria, $especialidad, $diplomado]);
```

you're passing array in tipoPrograma, and each variables is array too.